# Create a "hidden" page within Structure

Tags: structure, navigation

Is it possible to create a hidden page within a Structure similar to how the Structure addon in EE does? It is still available at the url, but is excluded from the navigation.

I know there are several ways I could handle this, 3rd level nav, possible custom field (lightswitch), additional structure for hidden items, etc. These just don't sound like perfect solutions. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a custom field actually *does sound like the perfect solution*. It's easy and consistent to check on all outputs and areas (sitemap/menu's/other navigations).

Comment: I've decided to go with the custom field (lightswitch) and show the field status on the structure listing so the client can easily see if it's hidden or not. I didn't know if there was some hidden functionality I was missing...thanks.

Comment: A Lightswitch sounds like a good approach, however for extra oomph you might want to implement a solution that makes sure there's only ever one entry within the relevant Section/Structure that has a `true` value for your particular Lightswitch field – the issue came up recently, see this thread: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/13330/1098